# Неправильно рассчитываются проценты при создании сетки на SASS

Tags: css, sass

У меня есть код создающий сетку.Для автоматизации этого я использую цикл.Проблема  в том что данные в цикле и данные без цикла получаются разными.В чем может быть дело?

```
$grid-spacing: 3%;
$per: 12, 6, 4, 3, 2.4, 2, 1.714285714285714, 1.5, 1.333333333333333, 1.2, 1.0909090;
$i: 11; 
@while $i > 0 {
    .col-#{$i}{
        float: left;
        width:  ((100% / nth($per,$i)) - ( $grid-spacing * $i / 12 )); 
    }
    $i: $i - 1;  
}
```

и того я получаю

```
 width: 8.08333%; (для первого значения)
```

а если пишу к примеру

```
.col-1 { width:(100% / 12) - ($grid-spacing * 11 / 12); }
```

то получаю

```
 width: 5.58333%;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неверный расчет ширины в цикле. Исправил, теперь считает верно. Код и пример ниже.

> Также - рекомендую использовать циклы `for` и `each` вместо `while` - они легче для восприятия. И рекомендую давать понятные названия переменным.

Код:

```
$grid-columns: 12;
$grid-spacing: 3%;
$column-widths: 12, 6, 4, 3, 2.4, 2, 1.714285714285714, 1.5, 1.333333333333333, 1.2, 1.0909090, 1;
@for $i from 1 through $grid-columns {
  .col-#{$i} {
    float: left;
    width: (100% - $grid-spacing * (12 / $i - 1)) / nth($column-widths, $i);
  }
}
```

И рабочий пример: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/f395e29554fd41f3259609f540da104a

Comment: ,ответ немног не тот, у col-12 width должен получится 100%,просто в этом то и загвоздка была,что если тупо на калькуляторе посчитать а не делать через цикл то именно 100% и получается,а через цикл нет.И гдето в этом и ошибка,но я немогу это разрулить

Comment: Исправил ответ, теперь считает верно

Comment: @ВиталийЕмельянцев столкнулся с подобной проблемой а как изменить тот ответ что вы дали чтобы получилось так 

    `.col-12 {
      width: 100%; 
    }
    .col-11 {
      width: 91.66666667%; 
    }
    .col-10 {
      width: 83.33333333%; 
    }
    .col-9 {
      width: 75%; 
    }`

Comment: @cheburashkarf, задать `$grid-spacing: 0;`, тогда у вас между колонками не будет промежутков, и значения будут такие, как вы указали.